# Post not appearing in wordpress site created with laravel

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I am using [corcel](https://github.com/corcel/corcel) to modify the wordpress content.

Post Model:

```
<?php 
namespace App;

use Corcel\Post as Corcel;

class Post extends Corcel
{
    protected $connection = 'wordpress';

}
```

And in the controller:

```
public function index()
{
       $post=new Post();
       $post->post_title="New post";
       $post->post_content="This is the post created with laravel.";
       $post->save();
}
```

The new post is created in database. i can see this record in `wp_posts` table in database of wordpress. but the new post is not appearing in wordpress site. what am i missing here?

Also updating the post works fine:

```
$post=Post::find(3);
$post->post_title="Edited post.";
$post->update();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to set the `post_status` to *published* in order to get the post displayed in front-end.

Try after adding `$post->post_status="publish";`

After updating the method should look like this.

```
public function index()
{
       $post=new Post();
       $post->post_title="New post";
       $post->post_content="This is the post created with laravel.";
       $post->post_status="publish";
       $post->save();
}
```

Comment: post_status is already publish. and i've tried manually but still isn't appearing.

Comment: What is the post_type ?